# setting date range of one field depending on input of another field jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

```
<table class='dates'>
    <form method='post' action=''>
        <tr><td>Start Date of Apply</td><td>: <input type="text" id="apply" name='start' placeholder='DD/MM/YYYY' readonly="true"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last Date of Apply</td><td>: <input type="text" id="last" name='last' placeholder='DD/MM/YYYY' readonly="true" disabled='true'/></td></tr>
        </td><td align='right'><input type='submit' name='cancel' value='Cancel'/></td></tr>
    </form>
    </table>
```

this is my html code.
my jquery code till now is this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#apply').datepicker({ showOtherMonths: true, selectOtherMonths: true, minDate: 0, maxDate: "2m"});
    $('#apply').onSelect({
        $('#last').prop('disabled', false),
        $('#last').datepicker({ minDate: $('#apply').val()+7D, maxDate: "+4D"})
    });

});
```

i'm using jquery ui datepicker with jquery 1.10.1 to select the date. i want to date range of `#last` from `(#apply).val`+7days to +4D upon selecting `#apply` date and also enable it. how to do that?

if i remove `onselect function` my datepicker works. else it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DHyPe/5/)

you need to pass in selectedDate to your event handler, and then convert it to a date object, and then add the 4 days and the seven days.

also, your better off using the custom event handlers built specifically for the datepicker to  handle events for it, onClose rather than a default one you'll have to build out code for.

here is the code from the fiddle:

```
$('#apply').datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "2m",
    onSelect: function(selectedDate){
        console.log(selectedDate);
       $('#last').prop('disabled', false);
       $('#last').datepicker({
         minDate: (function(){                 
            var min = new Date(selectedDate); 
            var newmin = new Date();
             newmin.setDate(min.getDate()+4);
            return newmin;
         })(),
         maxDate:(function(){
            var min = new Date(selectedDate);
            var newmin = new Date();
            newmin.setDate(min.getDate()+7);
            return newmin;
         })()
    });
    }
```

});

Comment: thanks man. You are a life saver. didn't expected a reply so soon...
works very fine.

i've 4 date input fields which gets enabled upon selecting the previous and the same rule follows for all as mentioned above.
shall i proceed as u mentioned or should i create a function?

Comment: @RatDon might as well create a function in that case.  Its more efficient.

Comment: when i add a date format `dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",`, the above code gives wrong output. how can i solve that?

Comment: @RatDon did you make sure you added a date format to both pickers?  And what do you mean by wrong formate?

Comment: when i add the dateFormat, for the date input of `#last` minRange and maxRange doesn't work. the calender shows all the months and years.

Comment: @RatDon it works here.  you just have to format the passed date back to the original form for the date calculations.  also added a destroy method to the on close.  http://jsfiddle.net/DHyPe/3/

Comment: thanks man. just replaced onClose with onSelect. and it works fine and thanks for the required code.

Comment: Dude, the code is having bug. unable to fix. it works for current month only. if i select a date from next month for the 1st date, the range of the 2nd input shows of current month instead of next month.

Comment: @RatDon see updated fiddle. newmin var needs to set date using selectedDate variable to keep month

Comment: thanks man. the code works fine. but if u have little time, can you make me understand what it's doing actually.

Comment: @RatDon setDate only sets the day of the month, not the month itself, so when initializing the date of newmin, it was defaulting to August because thats the current month